# How to add beads to Hair Particles System

Tags: animation, objects, particles, physics, hair

I tried to find a tutorial or something on the subject, but I found none.

I have a character with a long hair, beard and moustache (Poseidon) and I want to add hair beads to some of his braids, like a viking has on his beard for example, and I need them to animate along with the hairs. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: please don't ask same question twice. thanks.

Comment: I am not. Have you even read it?

Comment: Probably this could help you [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiSmodWGEus&ab_channel=THELUWIZART)

Comment: Yeah, I found this, first thing that pops up in google, but does not solve my problem I think. I guess it's impossible in Blender.

Comment: Can you explain why the particle instance method does not solve your problem?

Comment: @Blunder because it creates hundreds of randomly placed particles and I need like 3-4 beads on the right hair strands in the right position so I can then go and edit the hair so it looks squeezed where the bead is.

Comment: And why someone decided my question is duplicate?? I asked two completely different questions, the only common thing is they're both about HAIR, but that's it.............................

Comment: Yes, the question is *not* a duplicate. It looks like it was closed by a mistake. You can use the *flag* button to ask a moderator to re-open it. - About the beads: Just add another particle system with only 3-4 particles and use this for a Particle Instance modifier to place the beads. I once did a hair braid with a bow at the end. This can be animated very well with dynamic hair physics. A limitation is that you have to use *Children* because you can't squeeze several particles through the bead.